# How to copy the last row in datagrid

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I want to copy the last row value to new row

Code

```
   Dim rcount As Int32
    For i As Integer = 0 To gridview1.RowCount - 1
    gridview1.Rows.Add()
    rcount = gridview1.RowCount() - 1
    For j As Integer = 0 To gridview1.Rows(i).Cells.Count - 1
    gridview1.Rows(rcount).Cells(j).Value = gridview1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
    Next
    gridview1.Rows(rcount).Cells(1).Value = rcount + 1
    rcount = 0
    Next
```

The above code is working, but it is copying all the previous row to new row, i want to copy the last row to new

How to solve this problem.

Need VB.Net Code Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to copy the last row to the new row then do this.

```
    Dim LastRow As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim Newrow As Integer = DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows(Newrow).Cells(i).Value = DataGridView1.Rows(LastRow).Cells(i).Value
    Next
```

This will not work if you have a blank editable row always present. Then you need to subtract 2 from the "Dim LastRow" line.